# How to debug Visual Studio 2019 not connecting to Android x86 AVD

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-virtual-device, hyper-v

I'm trying to debug a NativeActivity C++ Android application from Visual Studio 2019, using the Visual Studio Android tools.

My system uses Windows 10 Pro, with Hyper-V enabled, running a number of other Hyper-V images (this cannot be turned off for reasons,) but the development Windows install is the "main" (host) OS.

I can build the sample application, and I can attempt to connect it to the VisualStudio_android-25_arm_phone AVD. However, one of two things happen:

1. If I just run out of Visual Studio, I get the error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Error installing the package. The device 'VisualStudio_android-25_x86_phone' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device.   XMCRemote3.Packaging        0
```

2. If I start the appropriate x86 AVD inside the AVD manager, the device actually starts up. If I then try to run in Visual Studio, I get an error dialog from the AVD Manager that the device and the host have different versions of ADB.

```
Device error: adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
adb.exe: device offline
```

This is the Visual Studio log when that happens:

```
1>Failed to start emulator.
1>emulator: Requested console port 5556: Inferring adb port 5557.
1>emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
1>Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
1>CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'
1>Error installing the package. The device 'VisualStudio_android-25_x86_phone' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device.
1>The device is invalid or is not running.
```

I don't think I have the "x86 device doesn't work on AMD" problem, as I'm using Hyper-V, and the device starts up and is interactive when I launch it manually.

Sometimes, I think I might have a "ADB port number" issue, because the error message in the log sometimes talks about ports 5556 and 5557, and sometimes about 5553 and 5554. However, I wouldn't know at all where that's coming from, or what to do with it.

And, like in case 2 above, sometimes it just claims ADB is mis-matched.

What can I do about this? Do I need to update the device image, or the local tools? Both were very recently downloaded/installed.

I'm targeting SDK version 21 for both minimum and target versions.
The SDK Tools version is 30.0.4, and the emulator is 30.1.5.
The Platforms installed are 8.0/26 and 7.1/25 (the list only goes up to 8.1/27)
Interestingly, there's no "NDK" version listed in the SDKs and Tools android settings app, even though Visual Studio compiles and links it just fine.

I wonder if the Visual Studio package is installing something on the side? If so, is there another tool to manage what this is than the "Android" sub-menu in the Visual Studio "Tools" menu?

Comment: You don't list out which version of the Android SDK you are using. Generally when I update the Android SDK, I rebuild from scratch a new AVD emulator image in case of compatibility issues. Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-with-hyper-v

Comment: I downloaded and installed all of them yesterday, so they should be in sync?

FWIW, my current workaround is to target a physical device, which works fine. Only the AVDs are ornery.